# Is there anyway to add data dynamically in a table UI of sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

I have a screen on which I am taking order number as an input from the user. Order has two part one the control information and other is the details (Line Items) I retrieve all the details (Line Items) in a table UI, and all control information in the associated fields.

I have made another portion on page which allows user to add any new line item in the details table UI. I made it workable up-till retrieving of details in the table but as soon as click the button to add new item in the table it is clearing all the previous details from the table and adding only the one which the user added last time.

I am using SAPUI5 API and oDataModel as the data model to retrieve the data from SAP

Comment: Can you show the code you used to add a new row? Remember, ODataModel works serverside, so if you directly bound your table to your ODataModel, you should add the new entry in your ODataModel (serverside), not on the client

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you cannot just add a new row to the aggregation, if it is bound to the model. Instead you should add a new entry to the data and let the databinding update the table control according to the changed data.

But we are aware this is a problem for the ODATA model and probably you do not want to add a new record to the server but just to the view. This feature hopefully will be available for the next version 1.28.

Another workaround for now would be creating JSONModel from OData Model and update JSONModel data.